# How to check if byte array contents form a double number and not a String Java?

Tags: java

I have byte array which usually have contents which from Double number as explained below:

```
//runs and prints 1.0
byte[] byteArrayValExpected = { 63, -16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArrayValExpected).getDouble());

//fails because byte array contents forms string "None"
byte[] byteArrayValUnexpected = { 78, 111, 110, 101 };
System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArrayValUnexpected).getDouble());
```

My question is: how do I find that byte buffer elements form a double number and it is not a string like "None" as shown above?

Comment: Hi @Scary Wombat I read these byte arrays and write in file csv file where double column is there I want to make sure even if string values comes I dont write that in double column space in csv file so thhrowing or catching exception wont work.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: it throws an exception if there are less than 8 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this is impossible.  A string and a double can each contain an arbitrary sequence of bytes.  So long as there are at least 8 bytes, it could be either.

The solution is to not encode doubles and strings as raw bytes in situations where you don't know which is which.

Comment: isn't the solution actually to prefix the array with a single byte discriminator which tells you what it actually is or better yet use something like google protocol buffers? (+1 though)

Comment: @simbo1905: Yup!  (I guess that would be a situation were you *do* know which is which ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the byte array has 8 bytes it could be either double either String, you can not be sure.

On the other way if you know that your strings are never 4 character long  (character in Java is represented on two bytes). In that case if the getDouble function throws an exception, the byte array is a String, else is double.

I suggest you to wrap the array near a type specifier.

Comment: Yes, I said that "If the byte array has 8 bytes it could be either double either String, you can not be sure. "

Comment: But if the user is sure that the Strings he use is never 4 character long(8 bytes) than he can call getDouble and check the exception.

Comment: @Scary Wombat I don't understand what you say with "it could either be an 8 byte string or a double.". Is written right there at the beginning of the answer.